# TypeScript: Convert a bool to string value

Tags: casting, type-conversion, typescript

I am unable to convert a boolean to a string value in TypeScript.

I have been roaming through documentation and I could not find anything helpful. I have tried to use the `toString()` method but it does not seem to be implemented on bool.

---

Edit: I have almost no JavaScript knowledge and came to TypeScript with a C#/Java background.

Comment: That's odd, the native JS `Boolean` supports [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/toString).

Comment: It seems that TypeScript definitely misses this basic implementation.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

This is either a bug in TypeScript or a concious design decision, but you can work around it using:

```
var myBool: bool = true;
var myString: string = String(myBool);
alert(myString);
```

In JavaScript booleans override the `toString` method, which is available on any `Object` (pretty much everything in JavaScript inherits from `Object`), so...

```
var myString: string = myBool.toString();
```

... should probably be valid.

There is also another work around for this, but I personally find it a bit nasty:

```
var myBool: bool = true;
var myString: string = <string><any> myBool;
alert(myString);
```

Comment: This is an acknowledged bug in TypeScript and is apparently planned to be fixed in the next release (0.8.2) - http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/362

Comment: toString() will definitely work fine as of 2016 (versions 1.6)

Comment: flag: boolean = Boolean("true"); if you need to convert to boolean from string

Comment: Apparently even for TS Version 2.9.0-dev.20180327 toString() will definitely NOT work! Had to use @Fenton's example here for it to work. WEIRD but fact.

Answer (score 48):

For those looking for an alternative, another way to go about this is to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like the following:

```
const booleanVal = true;
const stringBoolean = `${booleanVal}`;
```

The real strength in this comes if you don't know for sure that you are getting a boolean value. Although in this question we know it is a boolean, thats not always the case, even in TypeScript(if not fully taken advantage of).

Answer (score 23):

One approach is to use the Ternary operator:

```
myString = myBool? "true":"false";
```

Comment: One advantage of this approach is the converted string becomes literal types of `"true" | "false"`

Answer (score 3):

```
return Boolean(b) ? 'true':'false'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: If `b` is already a boolean, why use `Boolean(b)`?

Answer (score 1):

This if you have to handle null values too:

```
stringVar = boolVar===null? "null" : (boolVar?"true":"false");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know your value is always true/false, you can use
JSON.stringify(myBool)
it will give you value like 'true' or 'false'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).