# Angular2 does not pass parameters in POST request

Tags: spring, spring-security, angular

I am trying to pass a parameter using Angular POST request to Tomcat server, Spring Framework. Somehow I see that the parameter is there when it is sent, but it somehow does not arrive/properly retrieved on the backend. Here is the Angular2 code:

```
addCompany() {
  console.log("addCompany button clicked!");
  console.log("company name: " + this.input);
  let nameId = this.input;
  let body = JSON.stringify({ input: nameId });
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':this.getToken() });
  console.log("csrf token: " + this.getToken());
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/views/addcompany', body, options).toPromise()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("company added!");
      this.reloadList();
    });;
}
```

When I am trying to get it in Spring I am getting `null` for the parameter:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void addCompany(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    String nameId = request.getParameter("input");
    eventService.addCompany(nameId);
}
```

I tried also this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void addCompany(Model model, @RequestParam("input") String nameId) {
    eventService.addCompany(nameId);
}
```

And in Angular code I have been trying to change commas everywhere, like:

```
  let nameId = this.input;
  let body = JSON.stringify({ 'input': nameId });
```

etc.

I tried this one: [Angular2 - Http POST request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212341/angular2-http-post-request-parameters)

Following the suggestion `JB Nizet` I tried to create `POJO`:

```
public class Company {
public String input;

public Company() {
    this.input = "";
}

public String getInput() {
    return this.input;
}

public void setInput(String input) {
    this.input = input;
}
}
```

Register it in my `@Configuration` file:

```
@Bean
public Company getCompany(){
    return new Company();
}
```

And changed the request method to the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void addCompany(Company company) {
    eventService.addCompany(company.input);
}
```

After that I am getting `Company` object in the method with `input=null`.

Then I tried to deregister the `Company` `@Bean` from `@Configuration` and change the request method to the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addcompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void addCompany(@RequestBody Company company) {
    eventService.addCompany(company.input);
}
```

But after that I am getting `415 (Unsupported Media Type)` error.

In `pom.xml` I have the following jackson import:

```
    <dependency>  
         <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>  
         <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>  
         <version>1.9.10</version>  
    </dependency>
```

Substituting it for second jackson version solved the issue:

```
    <properties>
        ...
        <jackson.version>2.7.5</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a JSON object as body, and you expect to get a request parameter containing an attribute of this JSON object.

That won't happen. You need a POJO that matches with the structure of the JSON sent, take that POJO as argument and annotate it with `@RequestBody`. Jackson will unmarshal the JSON to the POJO and the POJO will be passed to your method.

Request parameters can be used if the request contains an application/x-www-form-urlencoded payload: the kind of payload you send when submitting a HTML form, without doing any JavaScript.

Comment: I tried the method that you propose and I am getting now a POJO with the parameter 'input' equal to null.

Comment: So, I suppose the binding needs to be fixed or smth, not sure

Comment: Edit your question and post the code of this POJO and the new code for the addCompany method. Also make sure that a non-null input is actually sent by the browser.

Comment: Don't register it in your configuration. It's not supposed to be a singleton Spring bean. Just a POJO created and populated by Spring each time the method is called. And, as I said above, the argument must be annotated with RequestBody: `public void addCompany(@RequestBody Company company)`.

Comment: OK, tried it and now the server responds with `415` error: `Unsupported Media Type for URL`. Probably, now Angular2 passes the data in the wrong format?

Comment: Do you have Jackson in the libraries of your webapp?

Comment: Yes, I have it in the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Don't use Jackson 1.9. Use the jackson2 version that your version of Spring recommends.

Comment: Data mapper's last version is 1.9: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl

Comment: Or should I use smth completely different?

Comment: No worries, got it, will try

Comment: Because you're looking at Jackson1. Jackson2 is there: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind. Which Spring version are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is solved, it was the wrong jackson version too. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad. I was out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
`let body = JSON.stringify({ input: nameId });`

try
`let body = { input: nameId };`

Answer (score 0):

Try  to use :

`let body:string='input='+nameId;`

And use this header

`let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':this.getToken() });`

Only for other readers if you want to send more than 1 parameter. use something & fro separating parameter . like below code

`let body :string='username='+username+'&password='+password;`