# Required parameter is missing: grant_type while accessing google token in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Required parameter is missing: grant_type while accessing google token in ionic2

**ERROR:-**

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

**code**

```
    let creds=JSON.stringify({
        'client_id':'251059024984-8113pdtb11gm8m4evdq59stlpvcab8cn.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'client_secret':'uVWZt_Vd5mMLXGQDo7lmAIUe',
        'redirect_uri':'http://localhost/callback',
        'grant_type':'authorization_code',
        'code':data
    });
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    console.log(data)


    this.http.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',creds,{headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
    },(error)=>{
        console.log('error in', error);
    })
```

when i check the api in Postman that working perfect

[image]

Comment: Try to remove json.stringify and leave only {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let creds = 'client_id=251059024984-8113pdtb11gm8m4evdq59stlpvcab8cn.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    +'&client_secret=uVWZt_Vd5mMLXGQDo7lmAIUe'
    +'&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback'
    +'&grant_type=authorization_code'
    +'&code=' + data
```

JSON.stringify() is not the right format

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212341/angular2-http-post-request-parameters

Answer (score -2):

**login.ts**

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log("hkjfghjksfgd")
    this.showLoader();
    this.authService.login(this.loginData).subscribe(
        (data) => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.result = data;
        console.log(this.result)
        localStorage.setItem('token', this.result.access_token);
        }, (err) => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
    });
}
```

**services.ts**

```
login(data: any): Observable<any> {
    let body = JSON.stringify(
        'ClientId = 5'+'&grant_type = password'
     );
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    console.log(data)
    return this.http.post(this.logindetail, body, options) // ...using post request
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```