# Get all comments help, API returns a 403 error

Tags: python, api, reddit

These are the headers I send with my get request to https://oauth.reddit.com/api/morechildren in python, however I get hit with a 403 error each time I try it. In the [#code](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/controllers/api.py#L3575) it seems like either the link is incorrect or that I'm not 'allowed' to see it.

```
('User-Agent', 'python:xxxxx:xxxxx by (by /u/XXXXXXXXXXXX)')
('Authorization', 'bearer <TOKEN>')
('children', <comma seperated list of ID36s for comments>)
('link_id', 't3_<ID36>')
('sort', 'confidence')
('api_type', 'json')
```

Comment: use this link `ssl.reddit.com` vs `oauth.reddit.com`, You can read more in reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/2m083c/add_oauth_support_for_apimorechildrenjson/

Comment: I read it but the oauth link is the one I'm supposed to use.

Comment: You need to send the parameters in POST form values rather than JSON. Here's some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212341/angular2-http-post-request-parameters

Comment: Ahh thank you, the api specifies that GET could be used in place of a post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the parameters in POST form values rather than JSON. [Here's some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212341/angular2-http-post-request-parameters).