# How can I use useBasicAuth in a http get request within Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic2, basic-authentication

I need to make a http get request with a basic authentication, but I do not know how. I am using ionic2, angular & typescript.
My code:

```
    this.http.get("http://address")
     .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe( data =>{
        console.log(data);
  });
```

From the Ionic doc I see what I need, but I am new to these technologies and I am not able to use it: [useBasicAuth(username, password)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/#useBasicAuth)

I have tried these solutions, but it did not work: [Angular 2- Http POST request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212341/angular2-http-post-request-parameters)

**EDIT**

I have been trying the code below

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic xxxxxxx=');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.get("http://VLCwebServerAddress",options)
```

or even

`this.http.get("http://VLCwebServerAddress",headers)`

If the second parameter is *headers* I get the response 401, so the Auth failed.

If the second parameter is *options* I get  `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 501` which [I've read](http://restlet.com/company/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/) it's related with CORS in the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it. I was mixing-up angular and Ionic2-cordova libraries.

**I didn't notice** that I had to use **`import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';`**

instead of using `import { Http, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`

(which was the code I've seen in tutorials and other questions) then, I am able to used all the methods that are listed in the [http documentation for Ionic2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)

**Bear in mind** that this plugin won't work while running `ionic serve yourApp` on the browser, but while running the app on a real device.

I've re-checked and tried several times doing the request with the http angular library but as soon as I add extra content like headers to the request, it stops working (not sure if it is because of the server). Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the username and token in sessionstorage or localstorage when the login in success. then you need to send them in the header of your request.

```
getUserByName(username: string) {
let url="http://localhost:8088/rest/user/userName";
let header=new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem("token")});

return this.http.post(url, username, {headers: header});
```

}

Comment: I got "cannot find getUserByName" if I try your code.
I'd like to know how can I use "getBasicAuthHeader(username, password)" which is defined in the docs, but without example of usage.

Comment: Do you have any idea on basic programming?  The code I wrote need to keep in service.

Comment: I easily get stuck... Nevertheless I think I've understood your code and I tried to implement as you could see in the edit. But still without success. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply append a header;

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic' + btoa('username' + ":" + 'password'));
this.http.get(url, { headers: headers });
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with your RequestOptions add the following parameter

```
withCredentials: true
```