# Angular 4 Http POST not working

Tags: javascript, angular, http-post, angular-http, angular-httpclient

I hope everyone is doing great. I've recently started working with angular 4.4, i've been trying to post data to my api server, but unfortunately it's not working. I've spent like 2 days on it but still no success. And have already tried 6-7 article even from [angular.io](https://angular.io). 
I've tried both [**Http**](https://angular.io/api/http/Http) and [**Httpclient**](https://angular.io/guide/http) modules
but nothing seems to be working.

The problem is, whenever i try to post data to my server, Angular makes http **OPTIONS** type request instead of  **POST**.

```
this.http.post('http://myapiserver.com', {email: 'adam@example.com'}).subscribe(
    res => {
        const response = res.text();
    }
);
```

And i've also tried to send custom options with the request but still no success.

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded' });
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
options.method = RequestMethod.Post;
options.body = {name: 'Adam Smith'};
//options.body = JSON.stringify({name: 'Adam Smith'}); // i also tried this
//options.body = 'param1=something&param2=somethingelse'; // i also tried this
```

I was using ASP.NET core 2.0, but since it wasn't working i also tried simple php code, Here is the server side code for php. And it's also not working.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Note: Cors are also enabled on server. Plus I also tried simple get request and its working perfectly fine.

I'll really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: OPTIONS is a pre-flight checking request, if everything is OK it will make the POST afterwards. Are you sure the CORS configuration is correct? What outputs do you see, could you expand on *"not working"* with a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you get any strange response/header from the OPTIONS response?

Comment: Here is the request angular sending
https://pasteboard.co/GOBkz3Z.png
And response is empty Array() (since i'm using print_r($_POST) in server side (php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - Http POST request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212341/angular2-http-post-request-parameters)

Answer (score 7):

I solved it by setting the Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
  const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  const params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('mypostField', 'myFieldValue');
  http.post('myapiendpoint.com', params, options).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried passing headers as the third argument in the post menthod:

```
this.http.post('http://myapiserver.com', JSON.stringify({name: 'Adam Smith'}), { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) }).subscribe(
    res => {
        const response = res.text();
    }
);
```

make sure you import Headers from @angular/http

Comment: yes i already tried it, it's not working. And for the double check i just tried again but it's not working at all. Its submitting ajax request in OPTIONS http request type.

Comment: its perfectly hitting the server, but with wrong http method **OPTIONS** when it should be **POST**.
Check the screenshot of what angular is sending if i run your above code 
https://pasteboard.co/GOBkz3Z.png

Comment: check this answer, might be helpful! [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21783145/7764151)

Comment: i was finally able to solve the issue, Thank you so much for your help guys

Comment: great ! - you should post your solution whenever you get time for future references!

Comment: just did :-), Thanks again! really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and i used like this.(using FormData) try it. It work for me.

```
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append('email', 'adam@example.com');

this.http.post('http://myapiserver.com', formdata).subscribe(
    res => {
        const response = res.text();
    }
);
```