# how to call a post request from button? node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, angular5

how do i call controller from a click button?
i tried into postman it works well.. but i cannot call it into button on my front-end.

i am using nodemailer and node express to send email..

here's my code..

is this correct? - thanks in advance.

i am figuring out if my code is in correct or not.

**mailController.js**

```
// mail controller routes
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer  = require('nodemailer');

// get /api/mail/
router.get('/send-email', (req,res) => {
  res.send('GET response');
});

// post /api/mail/
router.route('/send-email').post((req,res) => {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2', 
        user: 'dev.xxx@gmail.com',
        clientId: 'xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        clientSecret: 'SY0-xxxx',
        refreshToken: '1/xxx',
        accessToken: 'ya29.xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'
      }
  })

  let mailOptions = {
    from: 'FReyes <dev.xxx@gmail.com>',
    to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Nodemailer test',
    text: 'Hello World!!'
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, res) {
    if(err){
      console.log('Error');
    } else {
      console.log('Email Sent');
    }
  })
});

// put /api/mail/
router.put('/send-email',(req,res) => {
  res.send('PUT response');
});

// delete /api/mail/
router.delete('/send-email',(req,res) => {
  res.send('DELETE response');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**server.js**

```
    var express     = require('express');
    var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
    var nodemailer  = require('nodemailer');

    var app         = express(); // Please do not remove this line, since CLI uses this line as guidance to import new controllers

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      // console.log(req);
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT,DELETE');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');

      //and remove cacheing so we get the most recent comments
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
      next();
    });

    var mailController = require('./controllers/mailController');
    app.use('/api/mail', mailController);

    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5015, () => {
      console.log('Server is running');
    });
```

**contact.component.ts**

```
  sendMail() {    
    const data = {
        to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Subject',
        txt: 'hello world'
    };
    console.log('asd');
    return this.http.post('localhost:5015/api/mail/send-email', data).map((response: Response) =>{
      console.log (response.json());
    });
  }
```

**html**

```
<input type="button" value="test" (click)="sendMail(data)">
```

Comment: Sounds like all you're asking is how to call `sendMail()` when a button is clicked, and your entire server mail code is irrelevant to the question?

Comment: yes... i want to know how to call the post function when sendMail() button is clicked

Comment: Ok... https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: ofcourse i have that button @ChrisG but my function inside to that button cannot call a server

Comment: Ok, so you see `asd` in the console, then what happens?

Comment: yes i can see the asd in the console.. but the function return this.http.post is not working.. i dont have error in my console

Comment: I just saw that you have `map()` instead of `then()` (you can also remove the `return`)

Comment: i got an error when i remove map instead of then()

Comment: Apparently angular works differently. Anyway, are you sure the mail code doesn't get called? Do you see "Email sent" in your node console?

Comment: i dont see email sent in my console when i clicked the button.. but when i used postman it shows email send and works perfectly

Comment: Which angular version is this? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46711946/angular-4-http-post-not-working?utm_medium=organic

Comment: it doesn't work either.. did you create contact form nodemailer express before?

Comment: Again, this isn't about express or mailing. This is about sending a POST request from angular. The server implementation doesn't really matter yet. *Which angular version are you using?* And what exactly does "doesn't work" mean? That's a completely useless statement.

Comment: I am using angular 5.. 
the post request button doesnt work.. 

But when i used postman it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you checking the POST request in the developer console's network tab? Does anything get sent?

Comment: nothing sent in console's network tab... i don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you fix the URL? `post('/api/mail/send-email' ...`

Comment: yup i already did... i don't know why it doesn't call a post request

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to add protocol name and return value in the map function

```
sendMail() {
  const data = {
    to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Subject',
    txt: 'hello world'
  };
  console.log('asd');
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:5015/api/mail/send-email', data).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: Right, I completely missed the malformed URL. Good catch!

Comment: doesn't request a post either in clicked button

Comment: @RichardFreyReyes also please add template code, where you added click

Comment: @RichardFreyReyes there is no data (sendMail(data))

Comment: @RichardFreyReyes I have updated my answer, you can try again

Comment: @RichardFreyReyes I think updated answer will help you

Comment: @NarekHakobyan oh thanks it works.. but i got an error http://prntscr.com/jt221l ... the email sends via button.. i will check this error. thanks a lot!