# Angular HttpClient post cannot send simple string parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, http-post

I want to send a request to a C# service which has a string as its parameter. I wrote an angular service like this:

```
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getCategory(categoryName: string): Observable<Category> {
    console.log(categoryName);
    return this.http.post("/category/GetCategory", { categoryName: categoryName }, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' }) });
  }
```

I also tried:

```
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getCategory(categoryName: string): Observable<Category> {
    console.log(categoryName);
    return this.http.post("/category/GetCategory",  categoryName , { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-type': 'application/json' }) });
  }
```

But when they both successfully send the request, the parameter is always null.
My C# service is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetCategory([FromBody]string categoryName)
```

Comment: The first approach is the correct approach, the second one is not. But as you said both of them don't work. In that case could you check if you are able to successfully receive the categoryName when you send it via Postman for eg?

Comment: If I remove [FromBody] I can receive it by Postman but with [FromBody] I cannot

Comment: I'm not so sure about your C# service. I don't even know why [FromBody] is used, but if you're getting it from Postman after removing `[FromBody]`, then with the first approach that you tried, you should also get it from Angular.

Comment: I go to the service but the parameter is always null.

Comment: have you tried using `JSON.stringify(categoryName)` in your typescript service  with `FromBody` in controller?

Comment: @MehrdadBabaki check if my above suggestion works. keep the content-type as `HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })`

Comment: @Niladri Thanks, but it seems I shouldn't use JSON. I found the answer on the link below.

Comment: try using [material autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) and try to move away from antiques like JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
 [Angular2 - Http POST request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212341/angular2-http-post-request-parameters)
I also should remove [FromBody] from my service parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I can offer my own solution :)
Angular:

```
Func(data: string): Observable<any> {
        let params = new HttpParams();
        params = params.set('data', data);
        return this.http.post("url", params);
    }
```

C#:

```
public IActionResult Method([FromForm]string data)
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Best and easiest solution**

```
this.http.post(this.serverAddress + API_ADDRESS + '?param=' + yourStringParam, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Niladri said, this worked for me:

> ... using JSON.stringify(categoryName) in your typescript service with FromBody in controller

Also this is important:

> ... keep the content-type as HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })

It works with the FromBody in the controller method :)