# Angular Service Call Loses Post Variables

Tags: php, angular, post

I'm making a service call from Angular 7.

```
   search(params) {

   let url = 'https://thisapp.com/api/search.php';
   return this.http.post(url, params);

   }
```

console.log of 'params'

```
  {keywords: "riches", recent: "false", magic: ["fun"] }
```

The 'params' are not being read into the $_POST variable in my script on the live server.  In Postman or my local dev environment, they do show up correctly.

```
<?php 

    var_dump($_POST); exit;
    --- the rest of the code ---

?>
```

In Postman:

```
array(3) {
["keywords"]=>string(6) "riches"
["recent"]=>string(5) "false"
["magic"]=>array(1) {
[0]=>string(3) "fun"
}
}
```

Live server:

```
array(0)
```

So it is not receiving the data as a $_POST array.  I'm thinking it's something with headers...

Comment: Check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35212341/2050306