# hitting an endpoint from angular8 returns 404

Tags: api, spring-boot, angular8

This is my first exercise in angular8. I am on the attempt to make a form that consumes an API written in springboot. The api written in spring-boot is never executed when trying to consume it from angular8 and here is the endpoint

```
http://localhost:8080/api/startreg




@PostMapping("/startreg")
    public ResponseData<Activity> addReg(
            @RequestParam(value="firstDate") String firstDate,@RequestParam(value="secondDate") String secondDate
            ,@RequestParam(value="username") String username) {

            try {
```

Here is the service.ts script

```
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/startreg';
createReg(activity: Object): Observable<Object> { 
    return this.http.post('${this.baseUrl}', activity);
  }
```

the html file of the angular8 is shown

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 gutter">
                <div class="sales">
                  <h2>From:</h2>
                  <div class="btn-group">              
                   <select [(ngModel)]="activity.firstDate" class="form-control" name="firstDate">
```

when I attempt to submit the form, from the browser console below error

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4202/$%7Bthis.baseUrl%7D", ok: false, …}
```

Please where I am getting it wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `this.http.post('${this.baseUrl}', activity);` won't invoke service with the value of `this.baseUrl`, you can find out why according to the error message. 
The URL you passed to `post` is still a **string** not a **variable**.

Please modify `service.ts` as follows:

```
...
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, activity);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Another problem is your service consumes request parameters, so you have to pass these URL arguments for HTTP request in `service.ts`.

The valid URL should look like this:
http://localhost:8080/api/startreg?firstDate=XXX&secondDate=XXX&username=XXX

But I am not familar with **TypeScript**, so I don't know how to do this. Maybe you can refer to [Angular2 - Http POST request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212341/angular2-http-post-request-parameters).

BTW, I strongly recommend that you should use `@RequestBody` rather than `@RequestParam` for your **POST** service.

Comment: Yes,  as expected. Because your service accepts request parameters but you didn't send them in `service.ts`.

Comment: please how do I send them and how do I return the response back to angular of successful entry. Much Thanks sir